# Python Alembic - create column that is pipe delimited concatenation of items in list in json

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using alembic to create a new column in a mysql table. The table has a column `source_list` that is json

```
{"sources": ["source1" "source2"]}
```

I want to create a new column, `sources`, that is a pipe-delimited concatenation of the list items.

```
"source1|source2"
```

There is a variable number of sources in the sources list.

The alembic upgrade call would be something like this.

```
def upgrade():
    op.add_column(
        "table_name",
        sa.Column(
            "sources",
            sa.String(32, collation="utf8mb4_unicode_ci"),
            server_default=sa.Computed("source_list->>'$.sources[0]'"),
        ),
    )
```

This would create a `sources` column with the 0th element of the `source_list` json.

How do I get this computed column of a pipe-delimited concatenation of all the elements in that list?